# Roll dice game if else statement not working

Tags: javascript

Here is the description of the code i need to write:

Deisgn the logic for a game that simulates rolling two dice by generating two numbers between 1 and 6 inclusive (one number for each die).

The player will choose a number between 2 and 12 (the lowest and highest totals possible for two dice).

The program will then roll the dice three times
 -- if the user's guess comes up in one of the rolls the user wins.
 -- If the guess does not come up computer wins.

We have not started arrays yet but I am to use a for loop and if else.

It is my if else statement that is not working.
Every roll comes up you lose.

Here is the code:

```js
randNumber = prompt("Please enter a number between 2 and 12");
while (randNumber <= 1 || randNumber >= 13) {
  alert("Input was incorrect, try again.");

  randNumber = prompt("Please enter a number between 2 and 12");
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  computerRoll = 1 + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 11);
  document.write(computerRoll + "<br>");
}

function rollDice() {
  var computerRoll = rollDice(2, 12);
}
var computerRoll = rollDice;

if (randNumber == computerRoll) {
  document.write("You win.");
} else {
  document.write("You lose.");
}
```

Comment: `rollDice()` has infinite recursion.

Comment: There is a clear syntax error in the code you pasted, making it difficult to answer your question, can you please correctly paste the code in your question?

Comment: `var computerRoll = rollDice;` This sets the variable to the function, it doesn't call the function.

Comment: just print randNumber  and computerRoll before if you will see the issue. your computerRoll = rollDice is reseting it

Comment: The `for` loop rolls 3 dice, not 2 dice. It doesn't save the result in a variable, though. The code that rolls the dice should be inside the `rollDice()` function,

Comment: The instructions say you're supposed to generate 2 numbers between 1 and 6, not one number between 2 and 12.

Comment: "*2 numbers between 1 and 6, not one number between 2 and 12*" just to reiterate - this is *important*. Simply generating a number between 2 and 12 will give you uniform distribution, rolling dice and adding them (or generating 1-6 twice) will give more of a bell curve - you are most likely to get `7` with lesser chance to get each number further away with `2` and `12` having the lowest chance of all. There is only position of the dice that can generate either - `1+1` and `6+6`, while `7` can be made via `1+6`, `2+5`, `3+4`, `4+3`, `5+2`, and `6+1`.

Answer (score 0):

- if the computer is trying to roll 2 dice, you need 2 random numbers, both converted to range 0 to 5, and then added, and adding 2.  (Try making a function to roll one die, and then calling it twice.)
- The rolldice() function does not return a value.  And it's computerRoll is independent of the outer computerRoll.
- the outer computerRoll is set to a function, which is never equal to a number.  This is why you get only losses.

Comment: I am not getting a syntax error when I run it. I didn't realize we had to two 2 dice (that's my mistake). Can someone please explain how I call the function? Sorry but new to all this and teacher is not a lot of help. Also how do I do the two dice of 1-6? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: In javascript, rollDice has the value of the callable function, while rollDice() calls the function and has the value of its return value. Some other languages can call without parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your help! I have learned a lot from you. I am sure I will be back with more questions as the semester progresses.

Answer (score 0):

if my translator is correct :

```js
let randNumber, computerRoll

do
{
  if (randNumber != undefined) {
    alert('Input was incorrect, try again.')
  }
  randNumber = parseInt(prompt('Please enter a number between 2 and 12')) // bce promt value is string
}
while (!(1<randNumber && randNumber<13))  // to also process NaN values (not a number)

document.write('randNumber  -> '+ randNumber + '<br>' )

for (let i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  computerRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() *6) +1  // first dice
  computerRoll += Math.floor(Math.random() *6) +1 // second dice

  document.write('computerRoll  -> '+ computerRoll + '<br>' )
  if ( computerRoll === randNumber ) break
}

if (randNumber === computerRoll) { 
  document.write('You win.') 
}
else {
  document.write('You lose.') 
}
```

Comment: Input validation: One of the hardest tasks to get right.  3.1415 gets through at this point.

Comment: @DavidG. I think it's a Gauss curve, the values in the center are those with the highest probability of distribution